# Sort a Rails model by its method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a `question` model, which has_many `votes` and `comments`.

I defined a method on the `question` model called `engagement_score` which is simply `votes + comments`.

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::base
  has_many votes
  has_many comments

  def engagement_score
    self.votes.count + self.comments.count
  end
end
```

How can I get all `questions`, sorted by `engagement_score`?

`Question.all.order("engagement_score ASC")` does not work since `engagement_score` is not a column in `questions`.

Comment: `engagement_score` is it a class method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind not getting back an array, then you could probably just use sort_by.

So something like

```
Question.all.sort_by { |question| question.engagement_score }
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, this sorts in descending order, do you know how to reverse it?

Comment: This will generate n+1 queries

Comment: Pavittar Gill is correct. My answer is not efficient. Use his.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
Question.includes(:comments, :votes).order_by_engagement_score

def self.order_by_engagement_score
  sort_by |ques|
   -(ques.votes.length + ques.comments.length)
  end
end
```

Comment: This sorts them in descending order, do you know how to reverse it?

Comment: edited my answer, `-(ques.votes.length + ques.comments.length)`